# How To Get The PHP session Value to My Node Js

Tags: node.js

Here I executed a `SELECT` Query `where User_id=1`. Here I need to Get `user_id` From Session Instead of '1'. (if php Session Contain the `user_id`)
I'm new to Node Js.

```
  //server.js

     var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
     io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
     fs = require('fs'),
     express=require('express'),
     session=require('express-session'),
     mysql = require('mysql'),
     connectionsArray = [],
     connection = mysql.createConnection({
       host: 'localhost',
       user: 'root',
       password: '',
       database: 'test',
       port: 3306
     }),
     POLLING_INTERVAL = 3000,
     pollingTimer;
   var appp=express();
   appp.get('/',function (req, res){
        res.json({ uid: req.uid });

   });





   // If there is an error connecting to the database
   connection.connect(function(err) {
     // connected! (unless `err` is set)
     if (err) {
       console.log(err);
     }
   });

   // creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
   app.listen(8000);

   // on server started we can load our client.html page
   function handler(req, res) {
     fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client.php', function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         res.writeHead(500);
         return res.end('Error loading client.php');
       }
       res.writeHead(200);
       res.end(data);
     });
   }

   /*
    *
    * HERE IT IS THE COOL PART
    * This function loops on itself since there are sockets connected to the page
    * sending the result of the database query after a constant interval
    *
    */

   var pollingLoop = function() {

     // Doing the database query
     var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users where user_id=1'),
       users = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query

     // setting the query listeners
            query
       .on('error', function(err) {
         // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
         console.log(err);
         updateSockets(err);
       })
       .on('result', function(user) {
         // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
         users.push(user);
              })
       .on('end', function() {
  // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
         if (connectionsArray.length) {

           pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);

           updateSockets({
             users: users
           });
         } else {

           console.log('The server timer was stopped because there are no more socket connections on the app')

         }
       });
   };


   // creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without any AJAX request
   io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

     console.log('Number of connections:' + connectionsArray.length);
     // starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
     if (!connectionsArray.length) {
       pollingLoop();
     }

     socket.on('disconnect', function() {
       var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf(socket);
       console.log('socketID = %s got disconnected', socketIndex);
        if (~socketIndex) {
           connectionsArray.splice(socketIndex, 1);
       }
     });

      console.log('A new socket is connected!');
       connectionsArray.push(socket);

       });

    var updateSockets = function(data) {
      // adding the time of the last update
       data.time = new Date();
       console.log('Pushing new data to the clients connected ( connections amount =                     %s ) - %s', connectionsArray.length , data.time);
     // sending new data to all the sockets connected
        connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
        tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
     });
       };

 console.log('Please use your browser to navigate to                      http://localhost:8000');
```

[image]

Comment: Why No one is Answering